# Updating records based on the largest value on its related table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables

Table A is as follows:

```
ID NAME VALUE
1  abc  0
2  lmn  0
3  xyz  0
```

Table B is as follows:

```
ID SUB_GROUP   VALUE
1  Category 1  10
1  Category 2  4
1  Category 3  8
1  Category 4  12
3  Category 1  6
3  Category 2  14
3  Category 3  0
3  Category 4  3
```

I want to UPDATE Table A by setting its VALUE column to the largest VALUE in Table B by matching the ID columns but only for the values in Table B in Category2 or Category 3

What might that MySQL query look like?

Comment: It's going to be an update with a subselect. Seems pretty straightforward. But that would depend on which version of SQL you are using.. ?

Comment: Is this an on-demand call that you want to make, or do you want TableA to **always** have the largest values as described?

Comment: I am running MySQL: 5.1.67 @Rob

Comment: On-demand (ie when I run my update script) but always having the largest value @leftclickben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  tableA a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID, MAX(Value) max_val
            FROM    tableB
            WHERE   SUB_GROUP IN ('Category 2','Category 3')
            GROUP   BY ID
        ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
SET a.VALUE = b.Max_Val
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97ef6/1)

Comment: Thanks @JW...I am going to give this a try now.

Comment: Getting this message "Every derived table must have its own alias" continuing to work on it

Comment: @H.Ferrence i'm pretty sure you have some typo on your query? can you show it to me so we can work it out? `:D` the query above works on fiddle.

Comment: It's because you are using a subquery but you didn't assign an alias on it. here's an example, [**>>CLICK_HERE<<**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bbc2/1) Remove `b` and build again and set what happens.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @JW -- awesome answer and solution (it was a typo in my query)